# Sum distinct values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, reporting, fetchxml

I need some help in achieving a functionality. The idea is to calculate the sum of duration for all distinct activities which the query is bringing. A couple of considerations

- The query is not SQL, its FetchXML (Microsoft Dynamics 365).
- Grouping is not done on Activity IDs instead Contact ID, and it has to be that way only.

Here is how the data looks like

`| Contact ID | a.activityid | b.activityid | b.duration |
|------------|--------------|--------------|------------|
| A          | a1           | act_1        |         15 |
| A          | b1           | act_1        |         15 |
| A          | c1           | act_1        |         15 |`

Now, I'm trying to `Sum(b.duration)` and it gives me result as `45`, but I want the sum as `15` because `b.activityid` is getting duplicated in the resultset.

In short `Sum of duration for distinct b.activityid`.

Can anyone help me out a little here?

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to make sense?  Why would you want a result of `15` if the values in `a.activityid` are different?  Either both `activityid` values are valid and therefore need to be included, or you need to change your query to not include the `a.activityid` value.

Comment: I knew you'd think that way :) but that's the way it has to be `a.activityid` is something different and the total should not include that. I'm getting 3 rows primarily because of `left joins`. If I ignore `a.activityid` then everything is pretty straightforward but unfortunately will have to live this constraint and figure out how this can be achieved.

Comment: Why not just have two queries in your report?  One for each `activityid` column?  This just smells of bad design...

Comment: That's a good suggestion but the queries are heavy and filling up 2 datasets would eventually timeout. But yeah I can think of probably this as a last resort

Comment: Did you found a solution for this issue?